# Switching a PAM8610 sound amplifier board with a Raspberry Pi or Wemos Di mini GPIO

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm a complete novice.

I want to be able to switch a PAM8610 sound amplifier board, which runs on 12VDC, with a GPIO that outputs 3.3VDC.  I know I need some sort of relay. The board draws around 2A and googling I found the LM338T.  Can I use a transistor?  Is this the right one? Do I need any other components to make it safe?

My plan would be to remove the jumper from the switch pins next to the pentitometer and run those pins through the transistors input and output.

Edit to add:  It occured to me after I posted that there might be less than 12v across those pins so I checked and in fact it seems like there is 7.25V across them.  Still to much to run through the Pi.

This is the datasheet for the underlying module:
https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/products_inactive_data/PAM8610.pdf

[image]

Comment: The LM338T is a voltage regulator and not a "transistor". Please provide a data sheet link for the module?

Comment: Thanks.  I added a link to the datasheet.

Comment: Use the shutdown pin if that's all the information you have and don't get frustrated if the shutdown pin isn't available on your module.

Comment: I want to be able to shut it off remotely via wifi.